# Programming laptop ('18)

Tags: laptop, development, web-development

I am thinking about replacing my old [Samsung 700T (Intel Core i5 3317U 1700MHz / 4Gb RAM / 3G / touchscreen)](https://www.svyaznoy.ru/catalog/notebook/7063/1638757/specs#mainContent) laptop.

[image]

Is there something on the market which is close to it in terms of usability, just more modern or am I looking for a unicorn ?

---

## Intended usage

- Software development;
- Internet browsing.

I.e. File system, CPU, and memory intensive labor + usability in terms of text (code) visibility on the screen. WiFi network independence is a **huge** bonus.

## Required parameters

- built-in 4G (LTE) adapter;
- 13" — 15" anti-glare display;
- 8th Generation Intel® Core™ i7 processor (or "better");
- 256+ Gb SSD (526 Gb is preferable);
- 8 Gb RAM with a possibility of upgrade (16 Gb is preferable);
- Great video card is **NOT required**;
- Touchscreen is **NOT required**;
- Budget is open-ended, but ideally below $1500/2000 USD.

## Nice to have

1. Back-lit keyboard;
2. 4+ hours long living battery.
3. Port-rich form factor.

---

**Close examples**

- [ASUS ZenBook UX430UA-DH74](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0768M9KVY) — Misses LTE adapter.

[image]

- [Dell XPS 13 (9370)](http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/xps-13/spd/xps-13-9370-laptop/fncwy604s) -- Misses LTE adapter; mixed reviews.

[image]

---

**Update**

Actually, this might be something I am looking for [ThinkPad X1 Carbon 6th Gen](https://www3.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-x/ThinkPad-X1-Carbon-6th-Gen/p/20KHCTO1WWENUS0/customize?)

Comment: Take a look at mysn.eu, I own a Slim 14 and am very happy as coding machine

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered the Dell Latitude 7490? For 1700 or 1800 USD, you can get a 14.1 inch screen, 16 GB of DDR4, an Intel i7-8650U (supposedly up to 4.2 GHz), and a 512 GB SSD. It also seems to have 4G capability. It does only have Iris graphics.

I'm sure the battery can hit 4 hours, and it has a multitude of ports.

Comment: Thank you! I've read a few reviews and it leaves me with a mixed impression. Things like "fan running for no reason" aren't acceptable for me. I used to hate another laptop with such issue.